# Parsec positions as offsets

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Can one easily get positions as offsets (as charcters from the starting of input) with Parsec? If so, how? Internally Parsec keeps the position as a data type having the source name, the line and column.

I would like to be able to write a parser like

```
pWithPos p = do left <- getPosition       -- gets the current position as an offset
                x <- p
                right <- getPosition       -- gets the current position as an offset
                return (x,(left,right))
```

which parses something using the parser p, and returns its result, as well its left and right position as **offsets**.

[`alex`](http://www.haskell.org/alex/) (a lexical analyser generator) for instance handles [positions](http://www.haskell.org/alex/doc/html/wrappers.html#id462357) keeping the absolute character offset, the line number, and the column number. I am missing the absolute character offset in parsec.

Comment: offsets from what? parsec already tells you the line offset from 0, and the column offset from 0. do you want e.g. offset in characters from the start of the file?

Comment: @DonStewart I want offsets in characters from the start of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to calculate the offset, given the input string and SourcePos:

```
offset :: String -> SourcePos -> Maybe Location
offset source pos = elemIndex pos positions
  where positions = scanl updatePosChar firstPos source
        firstPos = initialPos (sourceName pos)
```

Comment: Is this actually O(n) in the size of the full input, or am I missing something that makes this run more efficiently? I'd be worried about calling this in a parser with any regularity. It also looks like this will count tabs as some generally unpredictable value between 1 (or 0?) and 8 due to how updatePosChar works :(

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to get the current string index in Parsec, because Parsec does not keep track of that index. You could use the `ParsecT` monad transformer over a state monad and manually keep track of the parsed index.

Comment: How hard would that be? I suppose some primitives would have to be redefined, right?

Comment: It would be very difficult; you have to basically redefine every primitive and everything that depends on those primitives. There's no "parser state type class" that has a function you can replace. I would advise to instead redefine your logic that depends on the string index information. What do you need the information for anyways?

Comment: You can for example make a function that converts `(Line, Column)` and the input string into an index. If you want, I can show you how to construct that function.

Comment: I am just reading the masters thesis Generic Selections of Subexpressions, where appears the problem of keeping offset positions of tokens in a text editor. The author has found a way to get the offset of tokens with parsec, but I would like to solve this problem in a more elegant way.

Comment: A function which receives the input string and a (line,column) position and results in the corresponding absolute offset position seems to be easy: just find the offset of the start of each line by counting newlines, and add the column. I will try to write it.